# Java UI Manager look and feel (JTattoo) causes NULLpointer

Tags: java, macos, swing, maven, look-and-feel

I have a java project that runs with maven. I added the JTattoo to the maven dependencies and set the GUI manager to the HiFi team in the main class:

```
try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.hifi.HiFiLookAndFeel");
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

When I run my application, Netbeans does not show any error and everything seems to work fine. But when I run my application, most of my JLabels are not displayed and I get a NullPointer exception and the following stacktrace (my programm keeps running):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Component.java:2043)
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Component.java:2028)
    at com.jtattoo.plaf.JTattooUtilities.getRelLocation(JTattooUtilities.java:192)
    at com.jtattoo.plaf.hifi.HiFiUtils.fillComponent(HiFiUtils.java:42)
    at com.jtattoo.plaf.hifi.HiFiRadioButtonUI.paintBackground(HiFiRadioButtonUI.java:84)
    at com.jtattoo.plaf.BaseRadioButtonUI.paint(BaseRadioButtonUI.java:97)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
```

Anybody has an idea, what can cause this problem? If this problem can't be fixed are there any similar free alternatives for the JTattoo HiFi/noir theme?

Comment: Is the Look and Feel jar in the class-path? Are you taking care to set the look and feel and start the GUI on the Swing event thread?

Comment: Are you initialising it from within the context of the EDT?

Comment: Works fine for me, perhaps you should consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Thanks for the great reactions. My program is big, since I build uppon a SDK. I am a beginner so wouldn't know how to provide a code example. From my main I create (after setting the GUI manager) a JFrame and a mainmenu (extends JPanel), from this main panel I can open 1 or more new panels, on new frame(s) after which the main frame will close. The labels dissappear on the main menu frame/panel, when I open these new frame(s)/panel(s) from the main menu, JTattoo works fine. These new frame(s)/panel(s) are all started from new threads. So could it indeed have something to do with the threads?

Comment: Some sort of work around is to only apply it once I start the new threads, than the initial panel (mainmenu) will have the default look and feel and the newly opened panels will have the HiFi look and feel. I might have found a reason for the problem. The mainmenu has a private constructor (I use the singleton pattern to access this panel), allthough this main menu is not initilzed before I apply the HiFi look and feel..

Answer (score 1):

(a) Check your Java, there is known bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8043705

(b) Check your library: create new hello world-like application with jtattoo l'n'f - just a JFrame + JLabel

(c) Try to find the difference between hello world application and your real application.

Answer (score 0):

1- import JTattoo 1.6.13
2- replace code in main

public static void main(String args[]) {

```
      com.jtattoo.plaf.acryl.AcrylLookAndFeel.setTheme("Green", "INSERT YOUR LICENSE KEY HERE", "Company");
     try { 
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.hifi.HiFiLookAndFeel"); 
} catch(Exception ignored){
         System.out.println(ignored);}
     
     
     
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewjFrame().setVisible(true);
        
           
             
               
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.